# SQL Server database : amalgamate 90 database update scripts into a single script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that has been released for several years. I have updated the SQL Server database around 90 times and each time I have created an update SQL script, so when the user runs the new software version the database is updated.

I would like to amalgamate all the updates into a single SQL script to make deployment faster and simpler, is there an easy way to do this? I presume I could simply grab the latest database after it has run through all 90 updates via SQL Server Management Studio?

**EDIT**

For clarification; the software I wrote automatically applies new database updates when the user downloads the latest version.  This is done via C# / .Net and look for an embedded sql script on startup in the format ***XX_update.sql*** calling each script one by one i.e.

***1_update.sql*** - this creates the tables and initial data etc.  This was my initial release database.

***2_update.sql*** - updates to the initial database such as adding a new SP or changing column datatype etc

***3_update.sql***

***4_update.sql***

...

***90_update.sql***  (4 years and lots of program updates later!).

Ideally, I would install my software and create a brand new database running through all 90 update scripts.  Then take this database and convert it into a script which I can replace all 90 scripts above.

Comment: As @Gordon Linoff said, unless you give more information, at least a rough pickture, on what the updates do, (if not the exact Sql Statements), it's not possible to give a definite answer to this question.

Comment: I have updated the question to show how my updates work in my application by calling scripts one at a time.

Comment: What about data that has been inserted by users into those tables, when you "upgrade" the database ? Or does the transactional data go into some other database and this one is kinda configuration database ?

Comment: It would be for new customers, installing for the first time.  No data (other than the default data I add) at the stage.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

There is no "easy" way to do this.  It depends on what the individual updates are doing.

There is a process you can follow in the future, though.  Whenever an update occurs, you should maintain scripts both for incremental updates and for complete updates.  You might also want to periodically introduce major versions, and be able to upgrade to and from those.

In the meantime, you'll need to build the complete update by walking through the individual ones.

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar system at work and while I prefer to run the scripts separately I have amalgamated several scripts sometimes when they have to be deployed by another person with no problem.

In SQL Server the rule is that as long as you separate the scripts by `go` and use SQL Server Management Studio or another tool that process the batch separator properly there is no problem in amalgamating it, because it would look like separate scripts to SQL Server (instead of being sent to SQL Server as a one big script the tool send it in batches using the [`go` as the batch separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)).

The only problem is that if you have an error in the middle of the script, the tool would continue sending the rest of batches to the server (at least by default, maybe there is an option for changing this). That is why I prefer when possible using a tool to run then separately, just to err on the safer side and stop if there is a problem and locate easily the problematic command.

Also, for new deployments your best option is what you say of using a database that is already updated instead of using the original one and apply all the updates. And to prevent being in this situation again you can keep a empty template database that is not used for any testing and update it when you update the rest of databases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your updates manaually on the server. Instead, you can create a .bat file, powershell script or a exe. Update scripts in your folder can be numbered. The script can just pick up updates one by one and execute it over the database connection instead of you doing it.

If you have multiple script files and you want them to combine into one, 
rename these as txt, combine, rename the resulting file as sql.
https://www.online-tech-tips.com/free-software-downloads/combine-text-files/

Answer (score 0):

This is easy.  Download [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) and use that to create the deployment script.  If there's no existing database, it will create all the objects, and if targeting an older version it will perform a diff against the target database and create scripts that create the missing objects, and alter the existing ones.

You can also generate scripts for the current version using SSMS, or use SSMS to take a backup, and use a restore to in an install.